# Load Ag-grid grouped rows in sorted order of a column by default

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am grouping rows based 'tradeDate' by default and displaying them. Ag grid sorts the rows if I click on the column header. How can I achieve this beforehand and display the grouped rows in descending order of 'tradeDate', without the user clicking on header?

The things I have set:

In portfolio.component.ts

```
columnDefs = [  { headerName:"Fund Ccy", field: 'fundCcy' },
{ headerName:"As Of Date", field: 'asOfDate',  valueFormatter: this.dateFormatter,hide: true },
{ headerName:"Trade Date",field: 'tradeDate', rowGroup: true,hide: true, valueFormatter: this.dateFormatter },]


this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
  sort: 'desc'
};

this.defaultColDef = {
  resizable: true,
  enableValue: true,
  enableRowGroup: true,
  enablePivot: true,
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  autosize:true
};
```

Inside portfolio.component.html

```
   <ag-grid-angular
       
        class="ag-theme-alpine ag-grid-portfolio-history"
        [rowData]="rowData | async"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [modules]="modules"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
        (adaptableReady)="onAdaptableReady($event)"
        [adaptableOptions]="adaptableOptions"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
 
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: While you have posted some code here it is not clear what you have done to address your specific sorting issue. Could you amend your code example to include what you have tried?

Comment: @Marcus. Hi, we got it resolved. We were using adaptable tools which is a wrapper around ag grid. We found a way to do this by defining a custom comparer for descending sorting. It turns out that adaptable uses this comparer to sort the grid at start-up, which is what we wanted. 
Thanks for the help:)